# Implicit derivitave of a general ellipse

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

Consider an ellipse centered at the point $(h,k)$. Find all points $P=(x,y)$ on the ellipse for which the tangent line at $P$ is perpendicular to the line through $P$ and $(h,k)$. 
I know the general equation of an ellipse is:
$$a^2(y-k)^2+b^2(x-h)^2=a^2b^2 .$$
I need to find the derivative of it, and that the derivative of the tangent line is: $$(a(y-k)/(-b(x-h)),$$ but what do I do from there?

Comment: It makes no sense to say 'derived from ellipse'. Derivatives are defined only for functions. I imagine you want to get the implicit differentiation from (this is also something well defined) the   ellipse equation.

Answer (score 1):

Use implicit differentiation. Differentiate the equation of the ellipse with respect to $x$ to get $$2a^2(y-k)y' + 2b^2(x-h) = 0.$$ Thus the slope of the tangent line at any point $(x,y)$ on the ellipse is $$y' = -\frac{b^2(x-h)}{a^2(y-k)}.$$

Edit: unless $y=k$ in which case the tangent line is vertical.

Comment: Thanks but how do I find point P on the circle of which the tangent line at P is perpendicular to the line through P and (h,k).

Comment: The slope of the line through $(x,y)$ and $(h,k)$ is $\dfrac{y-k}{x-h}$. It needs to be the opposite reciprocal of $y'$ above (or undefined if $y' = 0$, or $0$ if $y'$ is undefined). This is enough information to determine both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So I would do that to solve for x or y right?

Comment: You are looking for a point so you need to solve for the pair $(x,y)$.